# What controller buttons does Firewatch require?

Tags: firewatch

I'm trying to decide what platform I should play *Firewatch* on: PC or PS4. I prefer PS4, but we only have one TV, so I'll end up playing most of the game via Remote Play on my PS Vita. This sucks if the game uses L3/R3, as the Vita implements them via touch-sensitive areas on the back. So, before I make my decision, I'd like to know **what buttons on the PS4** controller does *Firewatch* require?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a quick screencap of the DualShock 4 control scheme *from the PC version of the game*:

[image: Firewatch Controls (Dualshock 4)]

I can only assume the PS4 version uses the same control scheme.

Jogging is mapped to both L3 and Square, so you're not forced to use L3 if you'd rather avoid it, though it looks like the flashlight is only mapped to R3.